# I have added 4 tables in power query of excel and done transformation but while moving to data model i am getting 2 table only?

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot

I have done transformation on power query of excel and loaded 4 tables but I want to make relationship between the table ,in the data modeling [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9nDv.png)part I am getting only 2 tables I don't know why ? I have tried to go in power pivot > manage data and > diagram view but I am getting only two table

I want all four tables in my modeling part

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the `Data` tab in the ribbon in the main Excel window, and select `Queries & Connections`.
2. In the pane that opens on the right side, you should see the "Table queries". Right-click on each of the ones missing, and select `Load To...`. In the window that pops-up, at the bottom, select `Add this data to the Data Model`.